# base 13 12 11 10 HELP

Tags: number-systems

Convert the last four digits 122917 
number to base 13, where A, B, and C correspond to 10, 11
and 12

does anyone know how would i start this ?

Comment: Utilize the division algorithm recursively until the remainder is zero. With each iteration, the remainder becomes the next digit, moving from right to left.

Comment: $2917\to 7\cdot 10^0 + 1\cdot 10^1 + 9\cdot 10^2 + 2\cdot 10^3 + 0\displaystyle\sum_{i=4}^\infty 10^i \to \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i \cdot13^i$ where $x_i$ are whole numbers.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog You switched 9 and 1 in comment.

Comment: fixed, thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $2197=13^3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We write $$2917=\sum_{i=0}^nx_i13^i=x_0+13(x_1+13(x_2+...))$$
All $x_i$ are between $0$ and $C=12$. From the above equation, $x_0$ is the reminder of the division of number $2917$ by $13$. Subtract the reminder from $2917$, divide by $13$ and you get $$\frac{2917-x_0}{13}=x_1+13(x_2+...)$$
This means that $x_1$ is the reminder of division of $\frac{2917-x_0}{13}$ by $13$. And continue like that, until the result of the division is less than $13$.

Answer (score 0):

$122917 = 12*10^4 + 2917 = 12*10^4 + 13^3$

$10,000 = 4*2917 + 1212 = 4*13^3 + 12*10 + 12$

So $122917_{10} = C*(4*13^3 + C*A + C)+ 13^3=C*(4000_{13} + C*A + C)+1000_{13}$

Now $C$ is like $9$ but in base $13$.  $C*k = 13*k-k$

So $C*A = A0 - A$ so

$122917 = C*(4000 + A0 -A+C) = C*(4000 + A0 + 2) = C*40A2+1000$

$= 40A20 - 40A2$.

$0 - 2= B $; borrow the $1$.

$(2-1)-A=1-A =14-A= 4$; borrow the $1$.

$(A-1)-0 = 9$

And $40 - 4 = 39$

So  $= 40A20 - 40A2+ 1000=3994B+ 1000 = 3A94B$